# Spring batch is throwing UNKNOWN Exit status when a step fails

Tags: spring-batch

I'm using spring batch partitioning technique to process records in chunks. I have a controller to launch the job and partitioner for equal distribute of records among 40 threads. Since we've implemented paging and are using JPA in our project, that's why we are using JPAPagingItemReader. The writer class is implementing ItemWriter. Could someone please help me resolve this issue

```
org.springframework.batch.core.step.FatalStepExecutionException: JobRepository failure forcing rollback
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep$ChunkTransactionCallback.doInTransaction(TaskletStep.java:459)
    at org.springframework.batch.costrong textre.step.tasklet.TaskletStep$ChunkTransactionCallback.doInTransaction(TaskletStep.java:330)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate.execute(TransactionTemplate.java:133)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep$2.doInChunkContext(TaskletStep.java:271)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.scope.context.StepContextRepeatCallback.doInIteration(StepContextRepeatCallback.java:77)
    at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.getNextResult(RepeatTemplate.java:368)
    at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.executeInternal(RepeatTemplate.java:215)
    at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.iterate(RepeatTemplate.java:144)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep.doExecute(TaskletStep.java:257)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.AbstractStep.execute(AbstractStep.java:198)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.partition.support.TaskExecutorPartitionHandler$1.call(TaskExecutorPartitionHandler.java:139)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.partition.support.TaskExecutorPartitionHandler$1.call(TaskExecutorPartitionHandler.java:136)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Caused by: java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
    at java.util.HashMap$HashIterator.nextEntry(HashMap.java:926)
    at java.util.HashMap$KeyIterator.next(HashMap.java:960)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.collections.CollectionConverter.marshal(CollectionConverter.java:73)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.AbstractReferenceMarshaller.convert(AbstractReferenceMarshaller.java:69)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeMarshaller.convertAnother(TreeMarshaller.java:58)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeMarshaller.convertAnother(TreeMarshaller.java:43)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.AbstractReferenceMarshaller$1.convertAnother(AbstractReferenceMarshaller.java:88)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.collections.AbstractCollectionConverter.writeItem(AbstractCollectionConverter.java"
```

job-report.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:batch="http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch" 
    xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch/spring-batch-2.2.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/util 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-3.2.xsd">

    <job id="testChunkJob" xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch">
        <step id="testMasterStep">
            <partition step="testSlaveStep" partitioner="testPartitioner">
                <handler grid-size="40" task-executor="multiThreadedTaskExecutor" />
            </partition>
        </step>
        <batch:listeners>
            <batch:listener ref="baseJobListener" />            
        </batch:listeners>      
    </job>

    <step id="testSlaveStep" xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch">
        <tasklet>
            <chunk reader="testChunkReader" processor="testChunkProcessor" writer="testChunkWriter" commit-interval="50" />
            <batch:listeners>
                <listener ref="baseItemListener" />
            </batch:listeners>
        </tasklet>
        <listeners>
            <listener ref="baseStepListener" />
        </listeners>
    </step>

    <bean id="multiThreadedTaskExecutor" class="org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor">
        <property name="corePoolSize" value="40" />
        <property name="maxPoolSize" value="40" />
        <property name="allowCoreThreadTimeOut" value="true" />
    </bean>


    <bean id="baseJobListener" class="com.test.batch.listener.BaseJobListener" />

    <bean id="baseItemListener" class="com.test.batch.listener.BaseItemListener" />

    <bean id="baseStepListener" class="com.test.batch.listener.BaseStepListener" />

    <bean id="testPartitioner" class="com.test.batch.partitioner.TestPartitioner"/>

    <bean id="testChunkReader"
        class="com.test.batch.reader.TestChunkReader" scope="step">
        <property name="minValue" value="#{stepExecutionContext[minValue]}" />
        <property name="maxValue" value="#{stepExecutionContext[maxValue]}" />
        <property name="gtfContext" value="#{stepExecutionContext[gtfContext]}" />
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
        <property name="pageSize" value="40" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="testChunkProcessor" class="com.test.batch.processing.TestChunkProcessor" scope="step"/>       

    <bean id="testChunkWriter" class="com.test.batch.writer.TestChunkWriter" scope="step"/>         
</beans>
```

Comment: Can you provide your step configuration? It could be caused by the lack of `saveState=false` on your `JPAPagingItemReader` as per documentation specifies to use in a multi-threaded environment : http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/item/database/JpaPagingItemReader.html

Comment: @Thrax..Thanks for your quick revert. here is the step configuration for your reference